# C Manipulate Bits Within a Bit String

Tags: c, string, binary, bit

I am currently working on a problem where I am trying to manipulate bits within a bit string.

I am trying to take a signal mask given as:

`00101001`

and check it against a signal mask given as an integer using the AND and OR operators.

I have some code currently that takes an unsigned character and prints out its binary representation, however I'm not sure how to continue.

```
main() {
    int signal = 2;
    unsigned char a = 41;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", !!((a << i) & 0x80));
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

- *The purpose of the program is supposed to take the signal number given, set all bits equal to 0 except the number bit that is the signal number and use an AND operator to find out if the signal is set or not based on whether the value is 0 or 1.*

**Note:** Only one given signal number will be checked at run time.

Can anybody help me out with this problem?

Comment: Show your inputs, outputs, and expected outputs for your code. That will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The purpose of the program is supposed to take the signal number given, set all bits equal to 0 except the number bit that is the signal number and use an AND operator to find out if the signal is set or not based on whether the value is 0 or 1.

You want to get the bit mask out of a signal number *n*, this is achieved by left shifting `1` to the *nth* place. Then a simple `&` (bitwise and) is applied to check if the bit is set or not.

```
int checkSignal(unsigned int value, unsigned char signalNumber){
  unsigned int bitMask = 1 << signalNumber;
  return (value & bitMask) != 0;
}
```

`signalNumber` is stored as a single byte, given that an `int` bit size cannot be larger than 255; ideally you should check that it isn't larger than `sizeof(int) * 8`.

Note that the 1st signal bit is at index 0, thus depending on the numbering convention, you might need to remove `1` to the signal number.

```
int checkSignal(unsigned int value, unsigned char signalNumber){
  unsigned int bitMask = 1 << (signalNumber - 1); // number starts at 1
  return (value & bitMask) != 0;
}
```

Test:

```
main() {
  int signal = 2;
  unsigned char a = 41;

  /*
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      printf("%d \n", !!((a << i) & 0x80));
  }
  printf("\n");
  */

  printf("%dth bit of %d is %s set\n", signal, a, checkSignal(a, signal)?"":"not"); 

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Super confused. When I try using numbers 1-8 as the signal it says that that some bits aren't set when they are. Does it read from forwards to back or backwards to forwards? Also does the signal number start at 0 and go to 7 instead of 1-8?

Comment: I just edited my post. Please confirm that only 1 signal number needs to be checked at a time?

Comment: Used your edited post and it works. I will update my post with the relevant information. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would I take this further and modify existing bits in memory using a signal number? For example, if I give a signal number of 2 then I want my program to access the memory location of my unsigned char and change that bit to a 1. Currently I have a function `void ADDSET(unsigned char *signalmask, int SIGNUM) {
}` and a function call; `ADDSET(&signalmask, SIGNUM);`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you could use a bitwise OR (`|`) to change the bits and assign the result to the pointed value.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, all you want to do is a bitwise and, between `a` and `signal`:

```
if ( a & signal ) {
    printf( "Signal bit is set\n" );
} else {
    printf( "Signal bit is not set\n" );
}
```

For the values `a = 41` and `signal = 2` the above will output `Signal bit is not set`, since `41` does not have a bit set in the same position as signal does.

If `a = 42` or `a = 43` it will output `Signal bit is set`.

Comment: For some reason using the above code produces some unexpected results. At least ones that I hadn't anticipated. If I use a signal of 3 it says that the signal is set. However, in `00101001` the 3rd bit from the right is not set. What am I missing?

Comment: By the way! I am using an unsigned char, not a regular char.

Answer (score 2):

If the signal mask is given to the program as a string in binary representation, you can use `strtol` to convert it:

```
const char *maskstring = "00101001";
unsigned int mask = strtol(maskstring, NULL, 2);

printf("hexmask for binary %s is %#x\n, maskstring, mask);
```

If the mask is constant, convert it yourself and use the hex value.

Answer (score 0):

```
// input integer with current signal bits
unsigned int signalBits = atoi(signalString);

unsigned int signalOfInterest;
// note signalOfInterest will contain a 'power of 2' value
// such as 1 or 2 or 4 or 8 or 16 or 32 or 64, etc
// which represent the various possible signal bits

// test if signal bit is set
if( signalBits&signalOfInterest )
{ // then signal bit is set

}
else
{ // else, signal bit is not set

}
```